# hql spatial ST_MakeEnvelope

Tags: hibernate, hql, spatial, spatial-query

Just a "simple" question:

how is the syntax of postgis function ST_MakeEnvelope() in Hibernate HQL?

I couldn't find any documentations after searching 2 hours :/

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution was to create a jts polygon with my bounding box coordinates and then i used the hql function:

```
within(object.geometry, :polygon) = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `session.createSQLQuery` method, you will need to use native sql for this.

Comment: nope native sql is not needed. and because of the join fetch function of hql i prefered hql aswell